# Script does not work locally but does on server

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am just starting out with javascript and well, I am stuck and it's quite embarrassing too.

First I tried to load a local json file which would not work. I found out about that quite fast.

But when I fixed this mistake it's still not working.

What I do have is basically a copy of http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 which works in my browser, while my attempt does not.

Now I have two files:

data.js

```
var json =
{
    "name":"flare",
    "children":
    [
...
```

This is so I have my json ready without the need of a webserver

And I have an html file with the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .node text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="data.js"></script>
<script>
    alert("here");

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
            width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var i = 0,
            duration = 750,
            root;

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([height, width]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    alert("there");

    d3.json(json, function(error, flare) {
        if (error) throw error;

        root = flare;
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;

        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }

        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        update(root);
    });

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

    function update(source) {

        // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                links = tree.links(nodes);

        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
        nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

        // Update the nodes…
        var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

        // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
                .on("click", click);

        nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 1e-6)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

        nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
                .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

        // Transition nodes to their new position.
        var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

        nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 4.5)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

        nodeUpdate.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
                .remove();

        nodeExit.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 1e-6);

        nodeExit.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

        // Update the links…
        var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
        link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                });

        // Transition links to their new position.
        link.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", diagonal);

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        link.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                })
                .remove();

        // Stash the old positions for transition.
        nodes.forEach(function(d) {
            d.x0 = d.x;
            d.y0 = d.y;
        });
    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
    }

</script>
```

as you can see it's now basically a 1:1 copy.

When I open that .html file though, my page stays blank.

How can this be? I understand that this would happen if I'd try to load a local .json file via the `d3.json` as that would try doing a http request, which would fail without a webserver to handle it.

But now that the json data is saved in a variable this behaviour makes no sense to me.

Please enlighten me! I'm trying to figure this out for a while now.

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: are you sure that "data.js" is on the server?

Comment: @durbnpoisn I have no server running. For the server from the tutorial: no, that makes an ajax request, that works obviously because the server deals with the http.

Comment: oh.  I read that backwards.

Comment: I got a few errors in my console like "can not read property tree of undefined". Use the console (F12 on chrome) to debug javascript, it's fundamental

Comment: @NicolaPedretti I get that in chromium, but in firefox I get different error (d3 not defined)-.- Hell this turns out to be a nightmare to debug if every implementation screams because of something else.

Comment: I just tried with firefox too and it gives me the same error in different words: "d3.layout is undefined" which is the same as saying that undefined has no property tree. check the d3 documentation, I could not find a property layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3.json(url[, callback])` creates a request for the JSON file at the specified **URL** with the default mime type `application/json`. In your code you pass the JSON object instead of a URL. Please try this:

```
d3.json(json, function(error, flare)
```

and assign `json` from `data.json` to `root`:

```
//d3.json(json, function(error, flare) { <-- this will be removed
//if (error) throw error; <-- remove this too not needed !
root = json;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}
root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);
//} <-- don't forget the closing brace.
```

Comment: As @Sorona said, they're trying to avoid making an AJAX request. I think the right fix is to just do `var flare = json;` and then run the code that would otherwise be in the callback to `d3.json`.

Comment: This make no sense ! so he can use `json` instead of `flare` !! @smarx

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
d3.json(json, function(error, flare) {
    if (error) throw error;

    root = flare;
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    function collapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(collapse);
            d.children = null;
        }
    }

    root.children.forEach(collapse);
    update(root);
});
```

with this:

```
var flare = json;

root = flare;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function collapse(d) {
   if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);
```

Comment: Duplicate answer anyway ! I've updated my answer based on your remark that was sufficient ! Anyway ....

Comment: Can you please elaborate why this is necessary?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Sorry, I posted this after your reply that made me think you weren't going to edit. :-(

Comment: @Sorona @IsmailRBOUH's explanation is right. `d3.json` makes an AJAX request, but you don't want to do that. So instead, just run the code that would otherwise be in the `d3.json` callback directly (using the value in `json`).

Comment: @Sorona Then you'll need to share what error you're seeing.

Comment: had to remove `if(error) throw error;` as well oO I assume that each boolean is default true in js -.-

Comment: Thanks a lot @smarx, but I'll accept Ismail RBOUH's answer as he was faster. Thanks still.

Comment: FYI, @Sorona, if you're still having trouble, consider that the example you copied uses v3 of D3, but your script tag brings in v4. Try `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` if you want to use this code as-is. (Otherwise you'll have to fix up a number of things.)

Comment: @Smarx: Yes, thanks... I did that, but I'll want to get it working with v4 as well.